# AIR GUI testing

Tags: apache-flex, testing, air, flex4

What do you guys recommend for AIR GUI testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with Robert,  Give flexmonkey a look.  We use it combined with Selinium for testing our web app and we have had some good results.

Also.. are you looking to do functional testing or performance GUI testing. What we have found that to do individual GUI testing profiling combined with programmatic sampling is a good starting point.  If regression testing is what you are looking for FlexMonkey is a good start.

If you want to test load performance between your AIR app our QA department is in the process of evaluating tools and seem to be pretty positive on NeoTys's offereing.

Comment: I am looking for a functional regression testing.

Comment: Then FlexMonkey is a good place to start.  What I have found is that in terms of Enterprise test tools Flex is lacking, but with more Enterprise companies starting to use this technology I would expect this to change.

Answer (score 2):

Take care because there are some limitations with automation for AIR 1.x apps : (child windows are not supported in flex 3 automation.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not looking to use expensive technologies like HP QuickTest than http://www.gorillalogic.com/flexmonkey is a good place to start.

Comment: I gave flex monkey a shot but it seems to require Flash Builder Premium to integrate with Air Apps (some agent is missing from the standard build).
Is this a common pitfall between testing suites?